# Node.js Problems setting up Passport with Express and Mongoose

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose, passport-local

I'm new to Node.js. Trying to set up user account creation and log in using Passport. I can't ge it work. I am getting Unauthorized message although I am logging in with an existing user and pass. My code so far:

```
var express = require('express');
var http = require('http');
var path = require('path');
var request = require('request');
var app = express();
var passport = require('passport');
var LocalStrategy = require('passport-local').Strategy;
var MongoClient = require('mongodb').MongoClient;

app.set('port', process.env.PORT || 3000);
app.set('views', path.join(__dirname, 'views'));
app.engine('html', require('ejs').renderFile);

app.use(express.favicon());
app.use(express.logger('dev'));
app.use(express.json());
app.use(express.urlencoded());
app.use(express.methodOverride());
app.use(passport.initialize());
app.use(passport.session());
app.use(app.router);
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));
app.use(express.bodyParser());
app.use(app.router);
app.enable('trust proxy');

if ('development' == app.get('env')) {
}

var httpserver = http.createServer(app).listen(app.get('port'), function(){
  console.log('Express server listening on port ' + app.get('port'));
});

var mongoose = require('mongoose'),
    Schema = mongoose.Schema,
    passportLocalMongoose = require('passport-local-mongoose');

/* Database has _id field but i guess i don't need to add anything here?*/

var Accoun = new Schema({
    username: String,
    password: String
});

/* Database collection is called 'users'*/
Accoun.plugin(passportLocalMongoose);
var Account = mongoose.model('users', Accoun);

passport.use(new LocalStrategy(Account.authenticate()));
passport.serializeUser(Account.serializeUser());
passport.deserializeUser(Account.deserializeUser());

mongoose.connect('xxxmyconnectionstring');

app.get('/', function(req, res) {
  res.render('login.html');
});


  app.post('/login', passport.authenticate('local'), function(req, res) {
      res.redirect('/myteam.html');
  });
```

I need some expert help...

Regards,

Answer (score 1):

I believe you need a successRedirect and failureRedirect in your app.post.

Comment: I finally used an already implemented login app: https://github.com/braitsch/node-login Thanks